# Search Guard 5 - ][WARN ][c.f.s.c.PrivilegesEvaluator] Can not handle composite request

Tags: elasticsearch

I have just installed Search Guard, version 5.6.9-19.1, in elasticsearch 5.6.9 to make a PoC. **I'm getting 2 types of warning messages in elastic log.** 
I am using admin default roles and permissions to make requests. Files of elasticsearch, sg_roles and sg_roles_mapping are below.

```
**elasticsearch.yml**
searchguard.ssl.transport.keystore_filepath: CN=dev-keystore.jks
searchguard.ssl.transport.keystore_password: 
searchguard.ssl.transport.truststore_filepath: truststore.jks
searchguard.ssl.transport.truststore_password: 
searchguard.ssl.transport.enforce_hostname_verification: false
searchguard.ssl.http.enabled: true
searchguard.ssl.http.keystore_filepath: CN=dev-keystore.jks
searchguard.ssl.http.keystore_password: 
searchguard.ssl.http.truststore_filepath: truststore.jks
searchguard.ssl.http.truststore_password:
searchguard.authcz.admin_dn:                                
  - CN=sgadmin

**sg_roles.yml**

sg_all_access:
  cluster:
    - UNLIMITED
  indices:
    '*':
      '*':
        - UNLIMITED
  tenants:
    adm_tenant: RW
    test_tenant_ro: RO

**sg_roles_mapping.yml**

sg_all_access:
  users:
    - sgadmin

    - admin
```

The requests that I made were in kibana console:

```
GET /_msearch/template
{"index":"rt", "_type" : "rt-type"} 
 {"id": "getState","params": {"Key": "Issuer:9972"}}
{"index":"history", "_type" : "history-type"} 
 {"id": "getDaily","params": {"Key": "Issuer:9971","from": "2018-07-30T00:00:00"}}
```

The log message elasticsearch.yml:

[WARN ][c.f.s.c.PrivilegesEvaluator] Can not handle composite request of type 'org.elasticsearch.script.mustache.MultiSearchTemplateRequest'for indices:data/read/msearch/template here

==========================================================================

```
GET rt/rt-type/_search/template
{"id": "searchKey","params": {"Key": "Issuer:9971"}}
```

The log message elasticsearch.yml:

[WARN ][c.f.s.c.PrivilegesEvaluator] Can not handle composite request of type 'org.elasticsearch.script.mustache.SearchTemplateRequest'for indices:data/read/search/template here

getState, getDaily and searchKey are templates.

**What does that mean? Is there any config missing? How can I avoid these messages?**

Thank you!